# What amount of heat can aluminium box sustain?

Tags: heat-transfer

So I want to install electronics inside 120 L aluminium box. The electronics have losses, which result in 50 - 150 watts heat. Can such size box contain these electronics without rising temperature above ~50°C? Is there a tool (online maybe) for measuring such thing?

The box size is not definite, as I could choose it bigger, so the heat would spread better. The box will be fitted outside, so temperatures would vary from -10 to 35°C. It will be put on a wooden floor.

The electronics wont have direct contact with box - they will heat surrounding air (there isn't the possibility to use box directly as a heat sink). A ventilation plug will also be installed. (No pressure difference with outside.)

Comment: maybe you want to use the word `dissipate`, instead of `sustain`